# Making multiple PDFs from 1 TEX file in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'd like to create multiple documents (output as PDFs after running pdflatex) whose source is from one file.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    This text will appear in the first PDF.
\end{document}

\begin{document}
    This text will appear in the second PDF.
\end{document}
```

This would be particularly useful because:

1. I could keep everything in 1 file, with a single, consistent preamble.
2. I could use `ifthen` or other loops to automatically generate various alternative forms of a document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible without some preprocessing of your file, i.e. using a scripting language to produce two separate documents then compiling them separately. Even then I don't think it's a good idea.

The first reason you think this would be useful is handled by putting your preamble in a separate document that is included in as many documents as you want using `\include`. The second aspect can be handled by using Makefiles and putting the conditional branching to build particular versions of a document in there.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a really simple preprocessor for LaTeX that embeds Ruby code directly into `.tex` files for this purpose and use the ERB template engine. Here's the source code on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/texrb/source/browse/texrb), if you want to take a look. There's not much to it, though I regularly use it from a `Ant`/`latexmk`-based build script and it has proved very useful for generating multiple version of my résumé. It works equally well on Linux/Mac OS X/Windows, assuming you have a working LaTex and Ruby installation.